# Expand a sin(x^3) in Maclaurin's series and find a 30th derivative at (0)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

I have a big task and problems with it.

I have to expand this function in Maclaurin's series. $$cos(x^{3})$$
I tried expand it as $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^n)/n!$$ but it's for $cos(x)$. So i don't know how to expand and rewrite $cos(x^3)$ in Maclaurin's series. Can you tell me how to find 30th derivative
of this function

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Add dollar signs before and after expressions so they'll appear in Latex.

Comment: Do you want sins or cosx? Your title says sins but your post talks about cosx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that

$$\cos y = 1 - \frac{y^2}{2!} + \frac{y^4}{4!} - \dots$$

So you substitute $y = x^3$ to get

$$\cos x^3= 1 - \frac{x^6}{2!} + \frac{x^{12}}{4!} - \dots - \frac{x^{30}}{10!} + \dots$$

If you differentiated both sides $30$ times, the constant term on the right will be $-\frac{30!}{10!}$. All following terms will be dependant on $x$. Substituting $x = 0$ to find the 30th derivative will cause them all to evaluate to $0$.

Comment: @Yiynam Thanks!

Comment: @user140810 Glad I could help! Since you are new to Math.SE: Please remember to mark any of the responses to your question as the answer via the tick besides it, if you found them most useful and sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.
$$
Plugging in $x^3$ then gives us
$$
sin(x^3)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(x^3)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.
$$
Differentiate this a few times with respect to $x$ to see the pattern for the 30th derivative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** When evaluated at $x = 0$, the only term of the series which is non-zero is the constant.

**Hint** The constant term of $f^{(30)} (x)$ is equal to the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in $f(x)$ multiplied by $30!$